# VHOST 404 Error after changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using Win 8.1.
I added a record to **hosts**

```
x.x.x.x www.example.com
x.x.x.x. example.com
```

Also added a record to **httpd-vhosts.conf**.

When I open **www.example.com** it works and the homepage is shown.

After changing URL to **www.example.com/xxx.html** I got 404 Error.

> The requested URL /DISK2/WWW/example.com/www/main.php was not found on
>   this server.

But it is on the server because when I open the **homepage** it is using it.

htaccess record:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^xxx\.html$ main.php?category=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^xxx$ http://www.example.com/xxx.html [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add **RewriteBase** to `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^xxx\.html$ main.php?category=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^xxx$ http://www.example.com/xxx.html [QSA,L,R=301]
```